# problem of \par in the paragraph

Tags: align, cases

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}

       \hat{\alpha} &= \begin{cases} 
                     \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}},  \,    &\text{if }  \hat{\alpha_1}>0 \, \hat{\alpha_2}>0 \\
                     \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}}+\pi,  \,  &\text{if }  \hat{\alpha_1}<0 \\
                     \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}}+2\pi,   \, &\text{if  }\hat{\alpha_2}<0 \,  \hat{\alpha_1} >0 \\
                     \text{undefined}, & \hat{\alpha_2}=0 \, \hat{\alpha_1}=0
                \end{cases}

    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

I need to numbering of this cases but when i put align code , the file not compiling because \par .... what is wrong please help me i attempt every probability to solve this

Comment: My answer to your previous question started by telling that you should not have blank lines in a math display.

Answer (score 3):

Do not insert blank lines inside math environments. (And, by the way, please communicate complete minimal examples, that is to say examples that reproduce your problem *and* can be executed “out of the box”, with `\documentclass{}`, `\begin{document}`, and so on.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   \hat{\alpha} &= 
   \begin{cases} 
     \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}},  \,    &\text{if }  \hat{\alpha_1}>0 \, \hat{\alpha_2}>0 \\
     \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}}+\pi,  \,  &\text{if }  \hat{\alpha_1}<0 \\
     \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}}+2\pi,   \, &\text{if  }\hat{\alpha_2}<0 \,  \hat{\alpha_1} >0 \\
     \text{undefined}, & \hat{\alpha_2}=0 \, \hat{\alpha_1}=0
   \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would also suggest some improvements for this formula, as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   \hat{\alpha} &= 
   \begin{cases} 
      \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}} &\text{if }  \hat{\alpha_1}>0\ \hat{\alpha_2}>0, \\
      \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}}+\pi &\text{if }  \hat{\alpha_1}<0, \\
      \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}}+2\pi  &\text{if  }\hat{\alpha_2}<0\  \hat{\alpha_1} >0, \\
      \text{undefined} & \text{if }\hat{\alpha_2}=0,\ \hat{\alpha_1}=0.
   \end{cases}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It can be still improved, I guess, but there are participants here that are (much) more competent than me to point out these improvements!

Comment: i write the code you written ... but the problem exist also

Comment: i asked about why the \par appear as problem

Comment: @Ritaana There are still blank lines inside your `align` environment, and besides some other errors I corrected (`\begin{document}` instead of `\end{document}`, `\usepackage` at the wrong places). Once these errors corrected, your example works fine in my installation.

Comment: i copy the code you written the problem is still in \par @F

Comment: Then I can't see where the problem is yet, since the same code works flawlessly with my installation, without any error messages or warnings. What are precisely the error messages you get? What is your own TeX installation?

Comment: the message appear {paragraph ended befor \align was complete. <to be read again> \par 1.88

Comment: Then there are still blank lines inserted inside your `align` environments. Maybe they are automatically inserted during your copy-paste… Blank lines (which are the same as `\par` commands) are forbidden in every math environments.

Comment: thnx alot you are wondefull @F